# Android OnDraw and onTouchEvent not working together

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ondraw

I am new to android development as well as the Java programming language and would definitely appreciate some help with this issue.

Currently I have some code which creates a canvas and draws a bitmap picture onto it, this appears to work. I also have another bit of code which detects where the users finger is on the devices screen and this also works. when I try to combine the two the bitmap will display but as soon as I click the screen the app crashes.

I have a feeling that this issue is with the canvas/bitmap side of this as i have also noticed that any widgets that have added to layout vanish when the canvas/bitmap feature is running.

This is the code for the canvas/bitmap:

```
public class myView extends View{

Bitmap image;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
public myView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bhead);

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float angle = 90;
    float imageCenterX = 50;
    float imageCenterY = 50;
    matrix.setRotate(angle, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
    Bitmap temp;
    temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bhead);
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, 100, 100,true);
    matrix.postTranslate(((width/2)-50), ((height/2)-100));
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, matrix, null);

}
```

}

and this is the code for the finger location on the screen:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

myView mview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mview = new myView(this);
    setContentView(mview);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }

    EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    txt.setText("X = "+ x +" Y = " + y);

    return false;
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: post a complete stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Your view hierarchy does not have an EditText with the id `editText1`. This is because you have set the content view to be a single instance of your class `MyView` (class names should start with uppercase) with this code in `onCreate()`:

```
mview = new myView(this);
setContentView(mview);
```

As a result, you get a NullPointerException on the line `txt.setText("X = "+ x +" Y = " + y);` because the previous line cannot find the EditText.

You need to include both views in the layout. You can use `MyView` in XML by writing its fully qualified name. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.your.package.name.MyView
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```